# Split multiple string and concat certain string python

Tags: python

So I have string like this:

```
Kompas.com - 14/11/2020, 11:20 WIB
```

And I want to split and concat certain string from string above with my desired output like this:

```
14/11/2020, 11:20 WIB
```

Actually I've done it with my code :

```
dates = "Kompas.com - 14/11/2020, 11:20 WIB"
datess1 = dates.split()[2]
datess2 = dates.split()[3]
datess3 = dates.split()[4]
datesss = datess1+(' ')+datess2+(' ')+datess3
print(datesss)
```

But is there any more efficient way than my code to get the exact output I desired above?

Comment: you do not need to `split()` three times, you can call it some variable eg `tokens = dates.split()` and then `datess1 = tokens[2]` etc. otherwise looks pretty efficient to me. as long as other strings (if there are any others) are of the same format. there are fancier ways (regex etc) but not sure why you'd want that for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split parameters (first is where to split, second is how many splits max)

```py
print(dates.split(' - ', 1)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
dates = "Kompas.com - 14/11/2020, 11:20 WIB"
datesindex = dates.index("-")+2
dates = dates[datesindex:]
print(dates)
```

create `datesindex`. it's a index where is `-` and do +2 because of `-` and space.
then change dates to `[datesindex:]`

Answer (score 1):

```
datesss = ' '.join(dates.split()[2:])
```